# TotalCommander - add start button to launch Visual Studio as an admin

Tags: windows-7, total-commander

My buddy is using TotalCommander as his file manager and program launcher, and I was wondering if there's any way to create a program launch button that will start up Visual Studio as an admin?

When I create a shortcut on my Win7 desktop, there's a setting in the Advanced options to launch Visual Studio as an admin. How can I do the same in TotalCommander?? Has someone figured that out yet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the button bar is shown (Options|Layout|Show button bar). Right click the button bar and select "Change...". Now you can add a new button (select also an icon you like), and put the path to your shortcut (.LNK) in the field "Command:"

That should do it.